# Both ArgoCD Applications trigger synch when only one Helm values file is updated

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I have two Argo Applications (one for staging and the other for prod) which use ArgoCD Notifications to trigger promotion of the application from the staging environment to production.

These files allow me to deploy my Helm Chart + Values to the appropriate environment.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-application-staging
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    notifications.argoproj.io/subscribe.on-deployed.promote: ""
  labels:
    env: 'staging'
    nextenv: 'prd'
    name: my-application
spec:
  project: my-project
  sources:
    - repoURL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/my-private-org/my-private-repo/main
      chart: my-chart
      targetRevision: 1.0.0
      helm:
        valueFiles:
          - $values/environments/staging/values/values.yaml
          - $values/variants/staging/values/values.yaml
    - repoURL: https://github.com/my-private-org/my-private-repo
      targetRevision: HEAD
      ref: values
  destination:
    name: staging
    namespace: my-appliction-staging
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      selfHeal: true
      prune: true
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
```

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-application-production
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    env: 'production'
    name: my-application
spec:
  project: my-project
  sources:
    - repoURL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/my-private-org/my-private-repo/main
      chart: my-chart
      targetRevision: 1.0.0
      helm:
        valueFiles:
          - $values/environments/production/values/values.yaml
          - $values/variants/production/values/values.yaml
    - repoURL: https://github.com/my-private-org/my-private-repo
      targetRevision: HEAD
      ref: values
  destination:
    name: production
    namespace: my-appliction-production
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      selfHeal: true
      prune: true
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
```

Both Argo Applications successfully deploy to their respective environments.

Note that the Values files for both Environment are located in the same github repo but in different folders.

The problem is that when I commit a change to `prod/values.yaml`, the Staging Application detects this as a change and triggers a resync with the Staging Environment.

I suspect the reason why the Staging Environment triggers a resync is that, despite the change being applied to `prod/values.yaml`, the Staging ArgoCD Application makes reference to the same github repo for its values file `staging/values.yaml`.

I attempted to fix the above issue by adding `path` to each environments' values reference.

```yaml
  <omitted for brevity>
  sources:
    - repoURL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/my-private-org/my-private-repo/main
      chart: my-chart
      targetRevision: 1.0.0
      helm:
        valueFiles:
          - $environments/values.yaml
          - $variants/values.yaml
    - repoURL: https://github.com/my-private-org/my-private-repo
      targetRevision: HEAD
      path: environments/staging/values
      ref: environments
    - repoURL: https://github.com/my-private-org/my-private-repo
      targetRevision: HEAD
      path: variants/staging/values
      ref: variants
```

The above is for the Staging application; I will omit the prod application as it is very similar.

I had hoped the above changes would work but ArgoCD (v2.8.4) cannot find the corresponding `values.yaml` file.  It is as if ArgoCD is ignoring the `path` attributes.

However, the [ArgoCD Docs](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/multiple_sources/#helm-value-files-from-external-git-repository) state the following:

> If the `path` field is set in the `$values` source, Argo CD will attempt to generate resources from the git repository at that URL. If the `path` field is not set, Argo CD will use the repository solely as a source of value files.

This suggests that I should be able to provide a `path` attribute for my `values.yaml` files.

How can I host values files for each environment in the same github repo while ensuring that only one Argo application will trigger a Synchronisation when the associated `values.yaml` file is updated?

Comment: You might be getting more help by posting this as a discussion on ArgoCD GitHub page.

Comment: If your first issue is that a notification is triggered during sync even when there's no change in the final manifests or the app, this is maybe more an issue with the notifications themselves first.

Comment: This is a known limitation and probably deserves a GitHub issue in the argo-cd repository.

Comment: I filed [this bug report](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/15528) and received some guidance on how to use the `path` attribute.  Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the question which I pose at the end of my original message.

Comment: I asked an updated question on the CNCF Slack channel ([link](https://cloud-native.slack.com/archives/C01TSERG0KZ/p1695128106630669)) but no answer.  Not sure if my question was too long or lacked the appropriate detail.